# Is Using a Boolean Such as isDestroyed Best Practice when Deleting Objects?

Tags: java, object, destroy

I have a destroy() method which removes all references to the object to be deleted.

Is it necessary or better practice to also have a boolean isDestroyed which indicate whether the object is deleted?

```
public class Eggplant {
    private boolean isDestroyed; 
    ... 
    public void destroy(){
       //remove all references to this Eggplant
       isDestroyed=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know which references to remove? If the object is truly destroyed (I'm assuming you are actually disposing the object / marking it for garbage collection), then how do you plan to check the `isDestroyed` boolean? It would help if you clarify what the intended behavior of `destroy` actually is.

Comment: How would you ever access `isDestroyed` if you've removed all references to the object instance?

Comment: With an automatic garbage collection, better tell a bit. Otherwise you risk people talking about WeakReference, SoftReference etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the destroy() function works.

If destroy() method returns only after other references are destroyed, than your destroy() method itself can return boolean.

If destroy() method is asynchronous in nature, that actual destruction can happen in some point in future, than isDestroyed() method can come handy to give a way for callers to know if actual destruction has happened or not.